# Will "Enabled Services" in a distribution provisioning profile cause issues with App Store Review if they aren't used

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

I have been developing version 2.0 features for an app that use the following services: SiriKit, App Groups, and Push Notifications. To do so, I've enabled these features on the App ID in the Provisioning Portal (developer.apple.com) and in the XCode Capabilities tab. I have been working in branches and none of my features have been merged yet to the master branch.

We are submitting version 1.0 soon to the App Store soon and I would like to ensure that having services enabled on an App ID and distribution provisioning profile is OK and won't cause any issues, even if we won't be using them in version 1.0.

It's also important to note that TestFlight builds have been uploading and processing fine for version 1.0 with the enabled services in the distribution provisioning profile, but also with these services set to "Off" in the XCode Capabilities tab.

If anyone has any thoughts or has experienced something similar, I would love to hear your recommendations. Thank you

Comment: there will be no causes regarding your App Store Review. Your app will be submit successfully, except there will be no other issue regarding this. But you can enable these services in your project. Otherwise you will get a mail from apple, that you are missing push notifications in your project. These services will not cause you any kind of issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that will not cause you any problems.  Having those services enabled in the provisioning profile simply means that you can use those services, not that you have to.  You may get a warning at some point, depending on what checks Apple adds to the binary check upon uploading your app to iTunes Connect.  But they will not reject you for it.

We had a service in our provisioning profile that was added for a feature we ended up never releasing, and it stayed in our profile for a couple years before we finally removed it for cleanliness.  But it never caused us any problems or raised any red flags during the review process.